# How to convert string to a different date format without error

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsdate

I have a date saved in a previous version of my app in NSUserDefaults in a particular date format as string within an array.

My problem is a lot of my app has changed since that version, and now I want to convert the saved date from previous version to the date format I will be using from now on

Here is the code I am using.

```
if userDefault.objectForKey("day") == nil {
            return
        } else {
            // Add the first date created from previous version
            let day = userDefault.objectForKey("day") as? String
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            let date: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(day!)!
```

The error 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' occurs on this line

```
let date: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(day!)!
```

Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1....

Comment: Just checked your code, works fine and changes the date format. Are you sure that something is returned as `day` from you NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Well, I am expecting something. When I download a previous version from the app store, set a date in it, then update it to current version through Xcode, the error above appears

Comment: Well you can't just expect something. I am pretty sure that there is nothing stored in NSUserDefaults with key 'day'. What you can do is, on your next release change your key and send a pre saved date with current working format and then allow user to change it.

Comment: I made an edit - there is something saved, and I am expecting it to show haha. I could delete the date they have saved, but I want it to work seamlessly

Comment: I know you want it to work seamlessly but if it does return nil there is probably nothing you can do. Are you sure that the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" matches the one saved in the NSUserDefaults? Sometimes if the format does not match, date is not returned from the date formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use forced unwrapping to unwrap but not sure `dateFromString` function return value != nil, it's case raising exception.

> Trying to use ! to access a nonexistent optional value triggers a
>   runtime error. Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil
>   value before using ! to force-unwrap its value.

You cannot make sure `userDefault.objectForKey("day")` is alway storing string of day any time.
And your storing string is become with format? `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

You better unwrap use optional binding to make sure, the data is not nil or valid format

```
if let day = userDefault.objectForKey("day") as? String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    if let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(day) {
        // convert success
        print(date)
    }
}
```